# Using Tikz to write a neural network equation with node matrices

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, neuralnetwork

I was trying to write some training materials for some of my students, to help them understand neural networks. The challenge is generally connected the graph/node diagrams back to the underlying matrices/tensors that are being computed. I found a really nice diagram, but I was not clear on how to do something like this. I am still a very novice tikz user, but I am trying to just get a minimal set of diagrams created so that I can tweak them and learn in the process.

But here is a picture that I found that I thought might be really helpful. I was wondering if someone could indicate how to create something like this. This is not like the usual network examples that we normally see, so I could not find an example of this on like Texexamples.net, etc.

Here is the picture.

[image]

I like this diagram better, because it connects the underlying matrix/tensor structure to the nodes. Any help in creating this would be appreciated.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328733/how-to-draw-recurrent-neural-network/328998#328998

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97579/how-to-put-node-in-an-accurate-place-how-to-use-dif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Neural network matrix diagram]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}   % needed for \text
\usepackage{tikz}      % needed for all the drawing
\usetikzlibrary{calc}  % needed for coordinate calculations
\newcommand{\grid}[3]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box)]
        \foreach \x in {1,...,#2} {
            \foreach \y in {1,...,#1} {
                \draw[fill=#3, color=#3] ($(0.4*\x, 0.4*\y)$) circle[radius=0.15cm];
            }
        }
        \draw (0.2, 0.2) rectangle ($(0.4*#2, 0.4*#1) + (0.2, 0.2)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
    \[
        \text{score} = 
        \underbrace{\grid{1}{3}{blue}}_{\mathbf{w}^\top} 
        \sigma \left(\underbrace{\grid{3}{4}{blue}}_{\mathbf{U}}
        \sigma\left( \underbrace{\grid{4}{6}{blue}}_{\mathbf{V}}
        \underbrace{\grid{6}{1}{red}}_{x}\right)\right)
    \]
\end{document}
```

Here's how I would do it.
Roughly speaking the macro defined `\grid{rows}{cols}{colour}` draws a `rows`x`cols` matrix of circles of the given colour. This is automatically put in a box and then since each matrix is its own `tikzpicture` environment it can be used in an equation in a similar way to any other maths command.

Comment: thanks so much for creating this. Yes, this is really helpful. Now I can go through and fiddle with this to make different network combinations. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem! There's much that could be improved still, it doesn't quite line up vertically with the maths and the brackets/underbraces are ugly together but I'm glad I could help

Comment: No worries. At least I have a starting point now.